# Android Fragment's child Fragment: can't show other Fragments when reopen from background

Tags: android, android-fragments

MainActivity has 4 Fragments, the first Fragment also has some child Fragments. The problem is: when app turns background for a while, reopen it, then MainActivity can only shows the first Fragment and its child Fragments, the other 3 Fragments can't show.

```
private void setTabIndex(int index) {

if (nowTabIndex == index) {
    return;
}

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();

unSelectAllTab();

switch (index) {
case 0: 
    if(!infoFragment.isAdded()) 
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, infoFragment,
                FRAGMENT_INDEX_INFO); 
    }
    else
    {

    }

    if (currentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
        //  fragmentTransaction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    fragmentTransaction.show(infoFragment); 

    currentFragment = infoFragment;
    infoTabLayout.setSelected(true);

    break;
case 1: 
    if(!marketFragment.isAdded())
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, marketFragment,
                FRAGMENT_INDEX_MARKET);
    } 

    if (currentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.show(marketFragment);
    currentFragment = marketFragment;

    marketTabLayout.setSelected(true);
    break;
default:

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, infoFragment);
    //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    break;
}

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
nowTabIndex = index;

}
```

In the code above, when reopen it from background for a while(the app has been killed in background), the first Fragment can show, the second Fragment can't show. How to solve it?

Comment: Fragments inside fragments is not supported in Android

Comment: what do you mean by cant show?? like if you go to that fragment it wont show?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes. I call the function `fragmentTransaction.show(marketFragment);`, but marketFragment won't display, the first infoFragment still showing instead of hiding.

Comment: @userM1433372 How can I change it? The app is written by the other developer, I want to change it a little to solve it. Is there an easy solution?  The child fragment uses ViewPager to manage, but the parent     fragment doesn't.

Comment: Make sure in you first fragment you are using ChildFragmentManager to show nested fragments.